# How do I log out of gdm from the command line?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

How do you log out in the most recent version of Ubuntu from a local terminal?

Comment: Control + Alt + Backspace... Not sure this is a safe logout, but probably the quickest!

Comment: @Wil: Ctrl-Alt-Backspace is disabled in recent ubuntu builds.  it was the traditional emergency-kill-X-windows, but it was implemented in the X server itself and has been removed.  you can add it back as a standard keyboard shortcut if needed.  but killing X-windows isn't exactly the same as logging out gently. :)

Comment: @quack quixote, I didn't write as an answer because I know it isn't exactly good! I never said gently! Anyway, +1 very interesting, I am only on Ubuntu 8.04 and had no idea it is no longer used in recent builds.

Comment: @wil: i think it was first disabled in Jaunty (9.04); there was a package called *dontzap* you could install to re-enable (it was still an X-server option then).  anyway see https://wiki.edubuntu.org/X/Config/DontZap for details.  there's some further discussion of other emergency keyboard shortcuts at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 5):

I use this:

```
gnome-session-save --logout-dialog
```

Comment: that's (certainly) the way to logout GNOME, not GDM (I use `i3` as window manager, so it can't work!)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop`

or `restart` if you want to log in as a different user:

`sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`

Comment: This doesn't work as recent versions of Ubuntu use upstart instead of a SysV init script to start gdm. Use "sudo service gdm stop" instead.

Like Control + Alt + Backspace this kills the X server (together with gdm). To just logout the current user Thomas Leonard's solution is usually better.

Comment: Sorry, it works, but is deprecated (for some reason I can't edit mycomment above anymore)